# Stream result of JDBC query with JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring with Java.

I need to return a `Stream` of objects from the database query (I use `ObjectMapper` to map them to JSON).

The query results can be quite large (over 500k objects) so I don't want to store them in memory.

I've done it with `JpaRepository`.

I'd like to know how it can be done with `JdbcTemplate` and if there would be an advantage to do so?

I.e ... can we optimize the throughput and memory usage using `JdbcTemplate` or perhaps even other libraries.

My goal is really at the end to find the optimal way to run a query and print all objects to an output stream in terms of memory/time/processing.

Comment: Upgrade to Spring 5.3 and use the newly added [`queryForStream`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForStream-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) methods. Or use a `RowCallbackHandler` if your intention is to write to an `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there will be an advantage with streams since it is a common abstraction for processing data without all of it being in memory. E.g. passing the stream to a HTTP response.

### Spring 5.3

If you use Spring 5.3, there is a convenient method `JdbcTemplate.queryForStream()` that can be used like this:

```
String sql = "select * from table";

Stream<Person > stream = jdbcTemplate.queryForStream(sql, (resultSet, rowNum) -> {
    return new Person(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString(2));
});
```

### Previous Spring versions

Older versions of `JDBCTemplate` does not have functionality for streams directly. But you can make a stream by using the underlying database connection:

```
String sql = "select * from table";

Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

PersonMapper personMapper = new PersonMapper();

Spliterator<Person> spliterator =
    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
        new Iterator<Person>() {
            @Override public boolean hasNext() {
                try {
                    return !resultSet.isAfterLast();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            @Override public Person next() {
                try {
                    if (resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) {
                        resultSet.next();
                    }

                    Person result = new Person(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString(2));

                    resultSet.next();
                    return result;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        },
        Spliterator.IMMUTABLE);

Runnable closer = () -> {
    try {
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
};

Stream<Person> = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false).onClose(closer);
```

Comment: It's really worth mentioning that result of `queryForStream` needs to be closed once fully processed (e.g. through a try-with-resources clause)

Answer (score 6):

Look at all the [`query()` methods of `JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#i32).

The ones that has a return type of `void` obviously don't build up the full data set in memory. They actually all take a [`RowCallbackHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html):

> An interface used by `JdbcTemplate` for processing rows of a `ResultSet` on a **per-row** basis.

The [`processRow()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html#processRow-java.sql.ResultSet-) callback method can then add the data to the streaming JSON text, ensuring minimal memory use.

That of course assumes that the JDBC driver doesn't load the entire `ResultSet` into memory, but that's a different issue, so solution (if needed) entirely depends on the JDBC driver in use.